# ASP.NET: How to extract parameters from request body?

Tags: iphone, asp.net, httprequest

In ASP.NET, how to extract the parameters from the request body of iPhone's POST method?

I am using the below code, the keys are same:

```
string username = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["username"].ToString();
string password = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["password"].ToString();
```